# AggregateRating rich result not showing the rating value, only votes

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

I have had the `AggregateRating` schema for the last month now and a couple of weeks back, the stars and the votes started to show on search results. But, one thing's missing and that's the rating value.

This is my schema:

```json
{
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "TVSeries",
        "aggregateRating": {
            "@type": "AggregateRating",
            "bestRating": "5",
            "worstRating": ".5",
            "ratingCount": "5",
            "reviewCount": "3",
            "ratingValue": "4.9"
        },
        "name": "Name"
        }
 }
```

This is what I am seeing in the search results.

> [image]

Ideally, I would like to see the rating precede the votes count like "Rating: 4.9 - 5 votes".

What am I doing wrong?